# Use Common Validation Strategy in GWT for all fields

Tags: java, validation, gwt

I am working on GWT application where I am creating dynamic fields (TextField, ComboBox, RagioGroup etc.). I am reading these dynamic details from a file and creating fields accordingly.

Now I want to apply common validation strategies for all fields like:
Field is mandatory or not;
Length check for field;
Allow or deny Alphabets, Digits, Special Characters. etc.

I read about BeanValidation in GWT version 2.4, but I am using GWT 2.3.
I want some idea how can I apply the common fields validation on different fields created dynamically.

I have read about `setValidator` on GWT fields, but how to use it for multiple validations on one field ?
Please suggest.